# Shorter option names for pytest fixture variants with long names

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I am testing a function with several incoming datasets defined as [fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html), but the fixture names get quite cumbersome to distinguish them from one another.

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def dataset_with_foo():
    pass

@pytest.fixture()
def dataset_with_bar():
    pass

@pytest.fixture()
def dataset_with_foo_and_bar():
    pass

def test_something(dataset_with_foo_and_bar):
    pass
```

Is there a way to define some kind of alias for the option name to be shorter? For instance, something like:

```py
@usesfixture("dataset_with_foo_and_bar", option_name="dataset")
def test_something(dataset):
    pass
```

Comment: I don't see how your example makes anything shorter or less cumbersome.  It seems more cumbersome, as you're adding a much more complex line of code.

Comment: Is it really? Would you prefer manipulating variables with long name within the test? Granted we can set an intermediate `dataset = dataset_with_foo_and_bar ` for each tests, but I feel there has to be a better way.

Comment: You may be right.  If I could see the use of the parameter in code, I might very well have a different opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the best way I could find to do it is by using [deferred parametrized fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html#deferring-the-setup-of-parametrized-resources):

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def dataset(request):
    mapping = {
        "with-foo": create_dataset_with_foo(),
        "with-bar": create_dataset_with_bar(),
        "with-foo-and-bar": create_dataset_with_foo_and_bar(),
    }

    return mapping[request.param]

def create_dataset_with_foo():
    pass 

def create_dataset_with_bar():
    pass

def create_dataset_with_foo_and_bar():
    pass

@pytest.mark.parametrize("dataset", ["with-foo"], indirect=True)
def test_something(dataset):
    pass

@pytest.mark.parametrize("dataset", ["with-foo-and-bar"], indirect=True)
def test_something(dataset):
    pass
```

There has been other attempts using [pytest-lazy-fixture](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-lazy-fixture/) or specialized decorator, but I find it a bit too hacky..
https://gist.github.com/wcooley/7472b8de6edb1e8ceda560843c0519a8

Answer (score 1):

Create a super fixture and helper function to get desired fixture with one fixture.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def super_fixture(fixture1,fixture2,fixture3):
    local_vars = locals()
    def helper(fixture_name):
        return local_vars.get(fixture_name)
    return helper

def test_a(super_fixture):
    # getting fixture1
    assert super_fixture("fixture1")
```

Comment: But then you cannot use the same name for several fixtures or you'll end up with name clashes, isn't it? I could potentially use indices in names (e.g. "dataset1", "dataset2", etc.) but then test readability would be even worst I feel. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I updated title to make issue clearer, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Updated the answer. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still find it cleaner to use deferred parametrized fixtures, but this an interesting workaround!